# How to cleanly do formatted string concatenation in clang++

Tags: c++, clang++

I'm using `clang++` on Windows to do some very basic SDL2 stuff, but I just found out that Clang++ doesn't come with the `<format>`, nor "[fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)" out of the box.

What I need is a more pretty way to concatenate a bunch of formatted strings, that would have been trivial elsewhere, and although I managed to get it to work I'm unhappy with the long repeated structures. This is what I got:

```cpp
std::string getInfo() {
    ...
    char ver[200] = "", verInfo[200] = "";
    sprintf (ver, "Compiled using SDL version  : %d.%d.%d \n", compiled.major, compiled.minor, compiled.patch); strcat_s (verInfo, ver);
    sprintf (ver, "and linked with SDL version : %d.%d.%d \n", linked.major, linked.minor, linked.patch);       strcat_s (verInfo, ver);
    sprintf (ver, "and using SDL_TTF version   : %d.%d.%d \n", ttfv.major, ttfv.minor, ttfv.patch);             strcat_s (verInfo, ver);
    return verInfo;
}
```

Q: *Is there a more compact and smarter way, and perhaps not using 2 buffers, to do this?*

---

**UPDATE:**

Managed to reduce the stream code significantly by using a custom struct in the stream handler, as suggested by user *Galik*. Code now looks like this:

```cpp
struct version_info {
    int major, minor, patch;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, version_info const& v) {
        os << v.major << '.' << v.minor << '.' << v.patch;
        return os;
    }
};

std::string getInfo() {    
    SDL_version aa;
    SDL_version bb;
    SDL_version cc;
    SDL_VERSION(&aa);
    SDL_GetVersion(&bb);
    SDL_TTF_VERSION(&cc);

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "SDL version  : " << aa << '\n';
    oss << "SDL linker   : " << bb << '\n';
    oss << "SDL_TTF ver. : " << cc << '\n';
    return oss.str();
}
```

...but I now get compilation errors.

---

UPDATE-2

Using `inline` instead of the *struct*, solves the problem:

```cpp
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, SDL_version const& v) {
    os << int(v.major) << '.' << int(v.minor) << '.' << int(v.patch);
    return os;
}
...
// same code
```

Comment: `std::string("Compiled using SDL version  : ") + std::to_string(compiled.major) + "." + std::to_string(compiled.minor)`? It uses no extra buffers.

Comment: `std::stringstream`  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt

Comment: *"or even "fmt""* Do you mean libfmt? It's not supposed to work out of the box. You need to download the library and build it.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just get the `fmt` library?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I was looking for something more compact than what i already have...You proposal would more than triple the length.

Comment: There is no reason not to use *fmt*, apart for not wanting to have to compile more libraries.

Comment: Someone proposed elsewhere to use something like `this -> ver += ver;`, but then I ran into some *static* problem instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this be acceptable?

```
// Old Way
std::string getInfo() {

    char ver[200] = "", verInfo[200] = "";
    sprintf (ver, "Compiled using SDL version  : %d.%d.%d \n", compiled.major, compiled.minor, compiled.patch); strcat (verInfo, ver);
    sprintf (ver, "and linked with SDL version : %d.%d.%d \n", linked.major, linked.minor, linked.patch);       strcat (verInfo, ver);
    sprintf (ver, "and using SDL_TTF version   : %d.%d.%d \n", ttfv.major, ttfv.minor, ttfv.patch);             strcat (verInfo, ver);
    return verInfo;
}

// New Way
std::string getInfo2() {

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "Compiled using SDL version  : " << compiled.major << '.' << compiled.minor << '.' << compiled.patch << '\n';
    oss << "and linked with SDL version : " << linked.major   << '.' << linked.minor   << '.' << linked.patch   << '\n';
    oss << "and using SDL_TTF version   : " << ttfv.major     << '.' << ttfv.minor     << '.' << ttfv.patch     << '\n';

    return oss.str();
}
```

If compactness is your goal you can be even cleverer by adding an output operator friend function for the version information.

Maybe something like this:

```
struct version_info
{
    int major;
    int minor;
    int patch;

    // formatting function for version_info objects.
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, version_info const& v)
    {
        os << v.major << '.' << v.minor << '.' << v.patch;
        return os;
    }
};

// ... a few bytes later ...

std::string getInfo3() {

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "Compiled using SDL version  : " << compiled << '\n';
    oss << "and linked with SDL version : " << linked   << '\n';
    oss << "and using SDL_TTF version   : " << ttfv     << '\n';

    return oss.str();
}
```

For the *formatting function* the term *friend* serves to make the function external to the struct, so it is NOT a *member function* despite it being declared inside the *struct* definition.

The *formatting function* parameters are a `std::ostream& os`and an object of the struct type it is being used to print. In this case `version_info`. So it takes an object of your type `version_info` and prints it out to `os`.

Whenever you have a command `std::cout << compiled;` the compiler replaces that with a call to the *formatting function* like this:

```
version_info compiled {2, 1, 0};

std::cout << compiled;
```

*...becomes...*

```
version_info compiled {2, 1, 0};

operator<<(std::cout, compiled); // a call to your formatting function
```

**BUT what if you didn't create the struct?**

If you are using the version information from another library like `SDL` you will have to create your *outputting function* as an inline free function like this:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL_version.h>

// ... a few bytes later ...

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, SDL_version const& v)
{
    os << int(v.major) << '.' << int(v.minor) << '.' << int(v.patch);
    return os;
}

// ... a few bytes later ...

int main()
{
    SDL_version compiled {2, 1, 0};

    std::cout << compiled;
}
```

Comment: That is actually very acceptable. I was looking at `std::ostringstream` link above, but didn't get any smarter, now I did! I can also rename the vars to get very short lines.

Comment: @not2qubit I added more information that may be of use to you if compactness is your goal.

Comment: Wow, this is really cool. With this, we basically don't need *fmt*, for small fringe usage cases.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask, how to read-understand the line with the *friend/operator* in it? There are names like `os` and `version_info` in there, that is not mentioned anywhere else in the code.

Comment: @not2qubit I added some explanation. The name `os`is just a parameter to your function and it will be whatever *output stream* (`std::ostream`) your function is called with. The word `version_info` is the name of the `struct`. I don't know what it is called in your original code so I made an example struct and I called it `struct version_info` for want of a better name.

Comment: This doesn't compile. I get `main.cpp:84:30: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char>' and 'SDL_version')   oss << "SDL version  : " << aa << '\n';`. How does the `ostringstream` know how to use that struct?

Comment: @not2qubit I added an `SDL` specific example.

Comment: Look promising. What's the `{2,1,0}` doing? (and why are the numbers reversed? ) And what happened to the `SDL_VERSION(&aa);` part, here?

Comment: @not2qubit I just used `{2,1,0}` to initialize the `SDL_version` structure with some random example data.  Obviously you do what you normally do to give it its values. I wasn't trying to replicate all your code, just show you how it works with examples.

Comment: Adding your `inline` *thing*, it now works with my code. Although it seem like magic to me.